# How can I access another program within my Universal Windows Application?

Tags: c++, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have a UWP app that i am developing for reasearch at my school. The app needs to gather data from a previously created Java program that returns a few values.

Inside of a console app that runs off of the terminal we can use a file path and a few arguments to start the java program perfectly fine using the system() function. EX. system("filepath argument1 argument2"). when we try this inside of the UWP App the system() function does not work. from the reasearch ive done it seems like system() is not supported in the UWP APP. when i call the system() function a blank cmd opens and closes immediately. using system("PAUSE") we can see that it is blank. is there any way around this? is there a way to bring the java program into my project soution and access it there? how would i go about doing that.

Comment: Note there are strong cases to be made for not using `system` in non UWP programs as well. For example, it really sucks when some cretin stashes a identically-named-but-harmful program to be found before the safe one.

Comment: I have heard system is not the best option but right now its the only way i am aware of. is there another way to run a program that returns values and use those values in my app.

Comment: Sadly I'm an old-school embedded systems dude with zero experience with UWP. Any answer I got for you would be via Google.

Comment: Any updates about this?

Answer (score 0):

You could launch the console app from the UWP app using [FullTrustProcessLauncher Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.fulltrustprocesslauncher?view=winrt-19041#remarks), then let the console app launch the Java program. You could refer to this question for more details:[Run an exe/batch file from UWP app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/311271/run-an-exebatch-file-from-uwp-app.html).